# configuring multiple project in sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube-4.5

I have 3 different project in my work-space. Now I want to run sonarqube with sonar runner in all three projects so I can see the report of all 3 projects in my console.
I tried using this by module but issue is that there's a single project under which I have to select a particular project to see the report.

is there's any way by which we can configure multiple project in sonarqube as separate projects and not as modules.

Comment: Which kind of project, module, workspace are you talking about ? Eclipse, Visual Studio, Java, Maven, Ant, ... ? Thanks

Comment: eclipse, gradel,java